# How configure a shared database with Play/Heroku?

Tags: heroku, playframework

I started by defining a framework ID as specified here

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/guide11

I called my server appnameheroku

Then I retrieved the database URL using

```
heroku config
```

from the console

I then added the following two lines to application.conf

```
%appnameheroku.jpa.ddl=validate
appnameheroku.db=postgres://....compute-1.amazonaws.com/etc
```

I then deploy the app and get the following error

Oops, an error occured

This exception has been logged with id 6963iilc8.  I'm using the free version of Heroku.

Comment: As Neil mentioned, you should be referencing the environment variable from application.conf rather than storing the URL value directly in the config. But I don't think this is causing your problem. Have you checked the logs? Use "heroku logs" to retrieve logs for you app and see what they say. There's probably an exception in there with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:  Storing config in the application code is a [bad idea](http://www.12factor.net/config), as it prevents Heroku from carrying out a lot of administrative tasks [on your behalf](https://status.heroku.com/20110116-credentials).

Therefore I would configure my application.conf as:

```
db=${DATABASE_URL}
jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
jpa.ddl=update
```

Heroku don’t recommend setting jpa.ddl to update for a real world production app. Use Play!’s database evolutions instead.